# I am confused about expressions, side effects, types, and values in C++?

Tags: c++

My teacher handed me this homework assignment. As a beginner, I'm just not sure at all where to start, or what this chart is even asking for. Can someone explain this all to me simply? The teacher wants us to fill in the type, side-effect (if applicable,) and value:

(http://i172.photobucket.com/albums/w32/Ravela_Smyth/Graph%201_zpslyxjgpde.jpg) 
(http://i172.photobucket.com/albums/w32/Ravela_Smyth/Graph%202_zpskoo3upjw.jpg)

Edit: Why do I keep getting flagged down? I don't understand what I did wrong?

Comment: http://www.learncpp.com/ .. as simple as it gets.If you enjoy it, then, buy a book on c++

Comment: All valid C++ expressions, but what is your teacher asking?

Comment: The teacher wants us to fill in the type, side-effect (if applicable,) and value:

Comment: @RavelaSmyth stackoverflow is not the place to do homework. Before asking question at-least show us what you have tried so far. **Note:** BTW i didn't down-voted your question, just to give you a try to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple:

Expression, some part of code, which does something, like a + b

Type, it is asking, what is the result type of the expression, that can get tricky in C++ :).

Side-Effects, the statement has result type and result of some sort but expression can in same time update some variables in the process as sife effects.

Here is an example:

```
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int k = 1;

auto rslt = cout << ++i << ( j += 2) << (k *= 5);

//now type of rslt would be? => &ostream, because &cout is of type ostream
// and we used overloaded operators for ostream and that overloaded operator
// is always returning ostream
// I hope you know auto, auto is leaving the decision about type on the compiler.
```

on screen there would  be:   125
now side effects:

```
++i // side effect of the operation is i:  1
(j += 2) // side effect of the operation is j: 2
(k *= 5) // side effect of the operation is k: 5
```

The value would be cout.